# GWT client side rest API

Tags: gwt

Instead of making RPC call from GWT client side (browser) can i directly call the RESTful services from GWT.

I don't want to add an overhead of adding (server side) .java files to call same API if those can be called from GWT client side java.

I'm fairly new to GWT, an example or pointer to a tutorial will help a lot!

Comment: Sure you can. GWT has the com.google.gwt.http.client package. http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/http/client/package-summary.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use [RestyGWT](http://restygwt.fusesource.org/), or also [Errai](http://erraiframework.org/) which have [JAX-RS Integration](http://docs.jboss.org/errai/3.0.2.Final/errai/reference/html_single/#sid-19398997).